# elementwise and on multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, logical-operators

I have several vectors and I would like to `&` them together (i.e. I would `&` all the the first elements of each vector, all the second, etc.). Assume they are all of equal length. The result should be a logical vector of the same length as the individual vectors.

I thought of doing this but it did not work:

```
a = c(NA, 1, 2, 3)
b = c(0, 1, 2, 3)
d = c(NA, 1, NA, 3)
do.call("&", list(a, b, d))
# Error in do.call("&", list(a, b, d)) : binary operations require two arguments
```

Comment: was just giving that a go. i think that's the right one.. always forget about those Reduce, Map, etc. Thanks! If you copy into an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `Reduce()`.

```
Reduce("&", list(a, b, d))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

This applies `&` element-wise down the list.  Check against

```
v <- logical(4)
for(i in 1:4) v[i] <- a[i] & b[i] & d[i]
v
# [1] FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

In fact the `for()` loop might even be faster than `Reduce()`.  I'll leave the benchmark to you.

Comment: the Reduce is better for my purposes since I have an unknown number of vectors that i simply bind to a list

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
mapply(function(a,b,c) a & b & c, a, b, d)
[1] FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```